# Couldn't find any iOS Development provisioning profiles when included in repo

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to migrate our app build process from AppCenter to DevOps and am having an issue with the provisioning profiles. Our family of apps is basically a master template of which multiple apps are built from with small configuration changes and different sets of provisioning profiles are needed for each app.

Ideally, I would like to have the profiles automatically pulled from Apple Developer but I cannot find a way to associate an account with DevOps. Nor could I get Fastlane's Spaceauth to work.

The second alternative I have come up with is to include the .mobileprovision files (programmatically pulled at runtime from a secure host) via the "Install an Apple provisioning profile" task and setting the source to "Repository". In my build logs, I see that both the app and notification provisioning profiles are correctly imported but at build time, fastlane (or xcode) complains that it cannot find the profile. The Bundle IDs in both the "Install an Apple provisioning profile" and in my build task match, so I am not sure what the problem is.

YAML example:

```
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 10.15.3'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 10.15.3
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Run Post Clone '
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: './appcenter-post-clone.sh'
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    verbose: false
- task: CocoaPods@0
  displayName: 'pod install'
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ios
    forceRepoUpdate: true
- bash: 'node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file=''index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false - -platform='ios''
  displayName: 'react-native bundle IOS'

#install provisioning profiles via repo
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: sourceRepository
    provProfileSourceRepository: ./certs/app.mobileprovision
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: sourceRepository
    provProfileSourceRepository: ./certs/notification.mobileprovision

# Install provisioning profiles via secure storage
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provProfileSecureFile: 'app.mobileprovision'
    removeProfile: false
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provProfileSecureFile: 'notification.mobileprovision'
    removeProfile: false

# attempt build with fastlane
- bash: |
   echo $FASTLANE_SESSION #tried setting spaceauth sessions to login to Apple Developer and fetch provisioning profiles
   #fastlane spaceauth login 
   sudo gem install fastlane
   fastlane gym --verbose --workspace "ios/*****.xcworkspace" --scheme "******"
   displayName: 'Fastlane build IOS'

# attempt with xcode
- bash: |
   xcodebuild "-workspace" "ios/*****.xcworkspace" "-scheme" "******" "-configuration" "Release" "DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=*******" "archive" "-archivePath" "*****.xcarchive" -allowProvisioningUpdates

# attempt with xcode 2 (with no signing)
- bash: |
   xcodebuild "-workspace" "ios/*****.xcworkspace" "-scheme" "******" "-configuration" "Release" "DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=*******" "archive" "-archivePath" "*****.xcarchive" -allowProvisioningUpdates CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
#resign with fastlane and include the cert. Fails with same error as above
- task: ms-vsclient.app-store.ipa-resign.IpaResign@1
  displayName: 'Resign ipa file'
  inputs:
    ipaPath: output/build.ipa
    signFileP12Path: certs/cert.p12
    signFileP12Password: '****'
    provFileProfilePath: ./certs/app.mobileprovision

# attempt with built in xcode command
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Xcode build'
  inputs:
    configuration: 'Release DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=******* archive'
    xcWorkspacePath: ios/*****.xcworkspace
    scheme: ******
    xcodeVersion: 10
    packageApp: true
    archivePath: *****.xcarchive
```

Comment: Why can't you just add the profile as a secure file then reference that in an IOS task?  I can provide an example if needed.

Comment: @StinkyTowel Thank you, I have tried that too. It didn't work either. I updated my post to show.

Comment: What build error/message do you get when using the secure file?

Comment: Although I can see my Bundle ID loaded in the InstallAppleProvisioningProfile tasks, it is always "Code Signing Error: No profiles for '{{notification bundle id}}' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching '{{notification bundle id}}'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild." The Bundle IDs match exactly.

Comment: Can you confirm that the provisioning profile was created using the singing cert you're referencing?

Comment: Yes, it is the same set of provisioning profiles and certificates that we use on AppCenter.

Comment: I have similiar issue, but no solution.